# Оптимизация базы данных (mysql) с большими данными

Tags: mysql, оптимизация, highload

Есть проект внутри компании (на Laravel 5.6(если это важно), который выполняет функцию логирования, при 500 тысячах записей подгрузка старых записей при пагинации становится невозможно долгой. Какие пути оптимизации можно сделать?
Я создал поле, где пишу id проекта, год и мес и индексирую это поле, то все равно для 1 проекта может набраться очень много логов, думал партиционированировать, но по какому признаку? опять же по месяцам? тогда прироста все равно не будет на данном этапе, т.к. логируется 1 проект. шардировать - можно конечно, но врят-ли компания еще сервера будет арендовать (компания небольшая). Какой может быть выход в этой ситуации?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82793/discussion-on-question-by-ruslan-mirzapulatov----mysql-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно добавить индекс на поле milliseconds и все условия выборки делать на основании этого поля.

Например, чтобы выбрать записи за август месяц, делаем запрос

```
SELECT * FORM logs WHERE milliseconds < :start ORDER BY milliseconds LIMIT 20;
```

Первый раз в :start передаем временную метку в миллисекундах

```
$d = DateTime("2018-09-01"); 
$start = $d->format('U')  . $d->format('v');
```

Чтобы отобразить вторую страницу, нужно запомнить значение milliseconds в последнее записи на первой странице. 
Пагинация при этом получится не "стандартная", а только с возможностью перейти на следующую страницу.

Зато все это будет работать шустро и не нагружать БД почти никак.

Comment: Не совсем понял насчет миллисекунд, в этом поле хранятся просто миллисекунды от времени на момент записи) Laravel не особо  хочет писать в поле created_at миллисекунды, по этому я вывел их в отдельное поле. (они несут чисто информационный характер)

Comment: @RuslanMirzapulatov Unix Timestamp в миллисекундах?

Comment: @RuslanMirzapulatov можно было б использовать поле created_at, но есть вероятность что произойдет 2 и больше записи в одну секунду. Поэтому я предположил, что в поле milliseconds пишется  Unix Timestamp в миллисекундах.

Comment: Можно было, но фишка в том, что потом фреймворк не дает изъять миллисекунды, и при выборке отдает их без миллисекунд))

Comment: @RuslanMirzapulatov поэтому и предлагаю использовать поле `milliseconds `. С этим все понятно?

Comment: Там хранится все что после точки, а не целиком

Comment: Тогда храните целиком

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое) (имел бы рейтинг, пославил бы +)

Comment: @Ruslan Mirzapulatov тут все про одно решение говорят: добавить в БД ключ на дату записи, и делать пейджер по датам: а не по страницам. Тогда будет быстро работать. Можно заморочиться, и сделать пейджер по страницам с ключом: но при этом необходимо будет добавлять скрипт индексации страниц в планировщик - делать более сложную систему с кешами вне БД.

Comment: @RuslanMirzapulatov можете принять мой ответ как ответ на ваш вопрос